# Json response with properties that contains ':'

Tags: angular, typescript, parsing, jsonresponse

How to get properties Json that contains ":" symbol

[image]

eveything is ok except the "properties" block, the following doesn't work

```
'comMedecin': success.entry.properties.os:commentaireSecretaire ? success.entry.properties.os:commentaireSecretaire : '',
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use properties named like this, you need to use:

```
success.entry.properties['os:commentaireSecretaire']
```

Short working example:

```
const json = '{ "a:b:c": 5 }';

const obj = JSON.parse(json);

// 5
console.log(obj['a:b:c']);
```